# HTML Form seemingly not posting to PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

Hello and thank you for your time.

Regardless of the amount of research I do, I cannot find an already-discussed solution to this problem.

The problem is that the submit button automatically redirects, seemingly without posting the form. It worked until I converted from MySQL functions to MySQLi. Everything else is working but this part of the website.

**HTML form (myaccount.inc.php):**

```
<div id="change-password">

<form class="clearfix" action="" method="post">

        <div><span class="he1">Change Password</span></div>

        <div>
            <?php include_once 'controllers/accountController.php'; ?>
        </div>

        <div><label class="fieldlabel" for="password">Current Password:</label></div>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" size="23" /><br />

        <div><label class="fieldlabel" for="passwordnew1">New Password:</label></div>
        <input type="password" name="passwordnew1" id="passwordnew1" size="23" /><br />

        <div><label class="fieldlabel" for="passwordnew2">Confirm New Password:</label></div>
        <input type="password" name="passwordnew2" id="passwordnew2" size="23" /><br />

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Change Password" class="bt_changepass" />

</form>

</div>
```

This form is then, for lack of a better term, controlled by some PHP.

**PHP (accountController.php):**

```
// Checking whether the Password Change form has been submitted.
if(isset($_POST['submit'])=='Change Password')
{
echo "<br />";

// Get the data from the database.
$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM ss_members WHERE usr = '".$_SESSION['usr']."' AND pass = '".md5($_POST['password'])."'");
$row = $sql->fetch_assoc();

// Will hold our errors
$err = array();

if($_POST['password'] == "" || $_POST['passwordnew1'] == "" || $_POST['passwordnew2'] == "")
{
    $err[] = 'All the fields must be filled in!';
}

if(!$row['pass'] == md5($_POST['password']) && $_POST['passwordnew1'] != "" && $_POST['passwordnew2'] != "")
{
    $err[] = 'Current password is not correct!';
}

if($_POST['passwordnew1'] <> $_POST['passwordnew2'])
{
    $err[] = 'New passwords do not match!';
}

if(!count($err))
{
    if($row['usr'])
    {
        // If everything is OK change password.
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE ss_members SET pass = md5(?) WHERE usr = {$_SESSION['usr']}");
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['passwordnew1']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

        echo "Password has been sucessfully updated!<br />";
    }
    else
    {
        $err[]='Something broke!';
    }
}

if($err)
{
    // Save the error messages in the session.
    foreach($err as $error)
    {
        echo $error . "<br />";
    }   
}

echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Your code also looks buggy first <form> must have action <form action="accountController">. Other thing is ur code is vulnerable to XSR attack. Please move the validation process above SQL Statement. Use of PDO in that case is also appreciated instead of mysql (Select Statement). and use of Place holder instead of direct request variable will also improve integrity of you code.

Comment: Is accountController.php a webpage or an include?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are including the

`<?php include_once 'controllers/accountController.php'; ?>`

after the headers have been sent.

You can either move the

`<?php include_once 'controllers/accountController.php'; ?>`

to the top of the page, inside the handler part, or you can submit the form to

`controllers/accountController.php`

using

`<form class="clearfix" action="controllers/accountController.php" method="post">`

Answer (score 4):

There is no `action` set in your `<form>` tag and it is sending the data to the same file. i.e., `myaccount.inc.php`.

Change it to:

```
<form class="clearfix" action="accountController.php" method="post">
```

Comment: therefore, is sending the data to the same html

Comment: That definitely makes it post, but it seems to be erroring out on the accountController.


Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in A:\wamp\www\path\controllers\accountController.php on line 9

Comment: @JoshMiller - You forgot to create object (`new mysqli..`) of `mysqli` class.

Comment: @Rikesh The object is created in includes/connect.php, which is included in the parent file of myaccount.inc.php. Other pages are using it just fine which is what is confusing me.

Comment: @JoshMiller - I'm not sure but can you check by  changing `include_once` with `include`.

Comment: I also tested to see if it was connected to the database (which happens in connect.php via the $mysql object), and it seems to be connected. I did this via mysql_ping().

Comment: That works, but causes tons of notices, such as: "Undefined variable: _SESSION in A:\wamp\www\swordslash\swordslash\controllers\accountController.php on line 11"

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

Give form action to `accountController.php`

`<form class="clearfix" action="accountController.php" method="post">`

Comment: @IvanIvković : Explain why not ?

Comment: Because empty action still sends the form to the current viewing page. And I think accountController.php isn't a webpage, it's a script that's a part of the webpage.

Comment: @IvanIvković :  I know that, my answer is to change the action. __"And I think accountController.php isn't a webpage, it's a script that's a part of the webpage."__ => He has not mentioned any thing about the pages

Answer (score 1):

change your `action` to this,because `accountController.php` is present inside  `controllers` folder.

```
<form class="clearfix" action="controllers/accountController.php" method="post">
```

Answer (score 1):

mysqli is a class, and the it's function query is not static so there, you must declare an instance of the mysqli class before you can use `$mysqli->query`.

You should put

`$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');`

before

```
$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM ss_members WHERE usr = '".$_SESSION['usr']."' AND pass = '".md5($_POST['password'])."'");
```

Comment: $mysqli is defined in another file, which is included in a parent file. Both the html form and accountController have access to the database, verified with mysql_ping().

Comment: Instead of following headers to stay on the same page, it is redirecting straight to index.

Comment: is myaccount.inc.php an actual webpage? or is it just included into another page?

Comment: It is included into another page, play.php

Comment: then you might check redirects on play.php. because having no a form with no action just redirects the submit to the same page, and if you put accountController.php as the action, you don't have redirects to any page after it is executed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25343/discussion-between-messy-coder-and-josh-miller)