# Echoing $_POST error on correct page

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, mysqli

thanks for reading.

I have an issue getting an error to echo on the correct page after a form submit. When the form is submitted, it redirects to **website.com/controllers/accountController.php**. I would like it to refresh the current page, **website.com/play.php?p=myaccount**

***Please note that the form is submitting, it is just printing the error on the redirected page instead of the page with the form.***

Please [take a look at my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151464/html-form-seemingly-not-posting-to-php) (related, but different question altogether).

**HTML form (myaccount.inc.php):**

```
<div id="change-password">

    <form class="clearfix" action="controllers/accountController.php" method="post">

        <div><span class="he1">Change Password</span></div>

        <div><label class="DEVON" for="password">Current Password:</label></div>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" size="23" /><br />

        <div><label class="DEVON" for="passwordnew1">New Password:</label></div>
        <input type="password" name="passwordnew1" id="passwordnew1" size="23" /><br />

        <div><label class="DEVON" for="passwordnew2">Confirm New Password:</label></div>
        <input type="password" name="passwordnew2" id="passwordnew2" size="23" /><br />

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Change Password" class="bt_changepass" />

    </form>

</div>
```

**PHP code (accountController.php):**

```
<?php

// Checking whether the Password Change form has been submitted.
if(isset($_POST['submit'])=='Change Password')
{
echo "<br />";

// Get the data from the database.
$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM ss_members WHERE usr = '".$_SESSION['usr']."' AND pass = '".md5($_POST['password'])."'");

$row = $sql->fetch_assoc();

// Will hold our errors
$err = array();

if($_POST['password'] == "" || $_POST['passwordnew1'] == "" || $_POST['passwordnew2'] == "")
{
    $err[] = 'All the fields must be filled in!';
}

if(!$row['pass'] == md5($_POST['password']) && $_POST['passwordnew1'] != "" && $_POST['passwordnew2'] != "")
{
    $err[] = 'Current password is not correct!';
}

if($_POST['passwordnew1'] <> $_POST['passwordnew2'])
{
    $err[] = 'New passwords do not match!';
}

if(!count($err))
{
    if($row['usr'])
    {
        // If everything is OK change password.
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE ss_members SET pass = md5(?) WHERE usr = {$_SESSION['usr']}");
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['passwordnew1']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

        echo "Password has been sucessfully updated!<br />";
    }
    else
    {
        $err[]='Something broke!';
    }
}

if($err)
{
    // Save the error messages in the session.
    foreach($err as $error)
    {
        echo $error . "<br />";
    }   
}

echo "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if(isset($_POST['submit'])=='Change Password')` statment is wrong.

Because `isset` always return `Boolean` so your if won't execute ever.

**OR**

You can use it as

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] =='Change Password')
```

Comment: The if statement is actually executing, and it is printing the error 'All the fields must be filled in!'. I just need to get the error to print on the same page as the form instead of redirecting.

Comment: @JoshMiller that can't be possible but if its really does then have you checked remaining code that contain header in it..??

Comment: @JoshMiller you need to return false or stop execution of code when validation gets fail..what happening now is you are just checking $err in if condition that is wrong it must be if(!empty($err)) it will check for array is empty or not then you need to retrun false or exit or use header()

Comment: `isset` on submit button is a wrong approach because some versions of IE never sends the attribute. Better to use `$_SERVER[' REQUEST_METHOD']

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])=='Change Password')
```

isset returns true of false when comparing it with the change password will return false

Regards.

Comment: The if statement is actually executing, and it is printing the error 'All the fields must be filled in!'. I just need to get the error to print on the same page as the form instead of redirecting.

Comment: Before redirecting, just call the javascript function which checks your desired condition before submitting.

Comment: There is jquery for this purpose, before redirecting you must use jquery

Comment: What's so obsession with jquery and ajax? It is a simple validation and without ajax, it should run fine.

Comment: ok leave ajax, you should use header function, and call the view back with the error label set.

Comment: The user didn't even ask for ajax/jquery/javascript.  I would remove this answer or even edit it, to only include the relevant parts.

Comment: I had it working before with header("Location: play.php?p=myaccount") but ever since I switched to mysqli, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

if(isset($_POST['submit'])=='change Password')
this usage is not valid in php

Comment: you should use Answer only to provide solutions; when you will have enough reputation you could add this as a comment